# !System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) is not working when hosted in iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jira-rest-api

Below is the post method. I  need to attach the files to the jira issue. For that, I had created the post API which calls the jira rest API for adding the attachment. It is working in my local when I run the code, but when I hosted in IIS server which is on my local machine, the file paths in the JSON object are not working.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]AttachmentFiles FilePaths)
    {
        string restUrl = String.Format("{0}rest/api/2/issue/{1}/attachments", FilePaths.Url, FilePaths.issueKey);
        var filesToUpload = new List<FileInfo>();
        foreach (var filePath in FilePaths.filePaths)
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {

                var js = @"{""errormessage"":""File  doesn't exist""}";
                object actionPlanModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(js);
                return Json(actionPlanModel);

            }
            var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
            filesToUpload.Add(file);
        }
        if (filesToUpload.Count <= 0)
        {
            var js = @"{""errormessage"":""No file to Upload""}";
            object actionPlanModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(js);
            return Json(actionPlanModel);

        }
       var result= SubmitFile(restUrl, FilePaths, filesToUpload);
        return Json(result);


    }
```

json object is below

```
{
    "Url": "xxxxx",
"username": "xxxxxx",
"password": "xxxxxx",
"issueKey":"MFS-8018",
"filePaths":["C:\\Users\\rkatakam\\Desktop\\diteplan.xlsx", "C:\\Users\\rkatakam\\Desktop\\InforWorklinks.docx"]
}
```

Can any one please help me on this?

Comment: By default IIS will not have permission to access a users directory, it seems unwise to change that, consider using paths relative to the site.

Comment: Aside from the security flaw, that is a config nightmare: the client shouldn't have to know the servers folder tree.

Comment: Hi @AlexK. @ Henk Holterman thanks for the suggestion. it has been solved by 

[link](https://docs.litium.com/more/best-practices/tips-tricks/give-directory-access-permission-to-iis-application-pool)
`Uri abdq = new Uri(@"" + filePath + "");

                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(abdq.LocalPath))
                    {

                        var js = @"{""errormessage"":""File  doesn't exist""}";
                        object actionPlanModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(js);
                        return Json(actionPlanModel);

                    }`